# How to count the number of months between two dates SQL

Tags: sql

How can I count the number of times each month occurs between two dates?

eg the number of times each month occurs between 24/8/10 and 29/2/12.

Comment: you should tag the database being used as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres you can use the generate_series(date,date,interval) function to construct the date table and then simply group by and count to determine how many times each month occurs in the range.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month from d) as month, count(*)
FROM generate_series('2010-8-24'::date, '2012-3-29'::date, '1 month'::interval) d
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1;

 month | count 
-------+-------
     1 |     2
     2 |     2
     3 |     2
     4 |     1
     5 |     1
     6 |     1
     7 |     1
     8 |     2
     9 |     2
    10 |     2
    11 |     2
    12 |     2
(12 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

[DateDiff](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/datediff.php) is the function you could use to compute the difference between 2 dates in various forms.

From the link as an example:

> SELECT DATEDIFF(month, '2014/01/01', '2014/04/28');
>
> Result: 3